# How to scroll with two fingers on Apple Mouse

Tags: mouse

On a trackpad scrolling is performed with two finger drag. On the Apple Mouse scrolling happens with a single finger drag. How do I change this to two finger drag? I don't see any options in preferences.

[image]

The reason for this is because when I use tools like VSCode the code view scrolls up and down erratically when placing the cursor or selecting text. This is happening in any application that has scrollbars.

Comment: There is no option to do that. This is known as 'didn't think it through properly; form over function' HUI development. Buy a better mouse. [Sorry, I've had several of those over the years. They all live in a drawer.] If I think carefully about it, the last Apple-supplied mouse I actually used was some time in the 90s...

Comment: @Tetsujin that's unfortunate. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Googling this question, rather than taking the time to type it, would have led you to the program MagicPrefs. The option is in there.

Comment: Just kidding. It no longer works and I never realized it as I hadn't used it in years. Bummer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).